# Latex minipage table alignment

Tags: latex

I'm attempting to align two tables in Latex document to be next to each other. Although this is working, the positions of the tables are off. The first is located lower than the second:
[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this? Below is my code:

```
\begin{table}[t]
\begin{minipage}{.55\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{l|l}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{WordNet}} & \textbf{FreeBase} \\ \hline
        domain\_region                                      & cause\_of\_death                \\
        domain\_topic                                       & ethnicity                       \\
        has\_instance                                       & gender                          \\
        has\_part                                           & institution                     \\
        member\_holonym                                     & nationality                     \\
        member\_meronym                                     & profession                      \\
        part\_of                                            & religion                        \\
        similar\_to                                         &                                 \\
        subordinate\_instance\_of                           &                                 \\
        synset\_domain\_topic                               &                                 \\
        type\_of                                            &                                
    \end{tabular}
    \label{table1}
    \caption{Relationships in WordNet \& FreeBase KBs}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Holdout Set Construction}}                                   \\
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{WordNet}}           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{FreeBase}} \\ \hline
        Word Removed & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\# Triples} & Name Removed        & \# Triples       \\
        adult        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{166}        & Alan Turing         & 15               \\
        botany       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{166}        & Carl Sagan          & 18               \\
        building     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{185}        & Frank Zappa         & 16               \\
        center       & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{180}        & Isaac Asimov        & 20               \\
        form         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{172}        & John Denver         & 16               \\
        game         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{267}        & Karl Marx           & 13               \\
        lake         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{227}        & Mary Astor          & 14               \\
        land         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{153}        & Su Song             & 13               \\
        mythology    & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{178}        & Tupac Shakur        & 14               \\
        room         & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{189}        & ...                 & ...             
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Ten words and a sample of 60 names used for constructing Holdout sets for WordNet and FreeBase, respectively. The numbers of triples that each             entity occurs in are listed to the right. These triples comprise the Holdout sets}
    \label{table2}
\end{minipage}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Probably better asked at the [TeX SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com) but you should also specify what kind of alignment you want: if you align the top, then the dividing lines will not align and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the `tabular`s with the same content, even though some rows might be empty. This will ensure they have the same height:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \mbox{}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering{\ttfamily
    \begin{tabular}{ l l }
      \toprule
      \\
      \multicolumn{1}{ c }{\normalfont\bfseries WordNet} & \multicolumn{1}{ c }{\normalfont\bfseries FreeBase} \\
      \midrule
      domain\_region                                      & cause\_of\_death              \\
      domain\_topic                                       & ethnicity                     \\
      has\_instance                                       & gender                        \\
      has\_part                                           & institution                   \\
      member\_holonym                                     & nationality                   \\
      member\_meronym                                     & profession                    \\
      part\_of                                            & religion                      \\
      similar\_to                                         &                               \\
      subordinate\_instance\_of                           &                               \\
      synset\_domain\_topic                               &                               \\
      type\_of                                            &                               \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}

    \caption{Relationships in WordNet \& FreeBase KBs.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.48\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c c }
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{\bfseries Holdout Set Construction}                                   \\
      \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries WordNet}           & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries FreeBase} \\
      \midrule
      \itshape Word Removed & \itshape\# Triples & \itshape Name Removed & \itshape \# Triples       \\
      adult        & 166        & Alan Turing         & 15               \\
      botany       & 166        & Carl Sagan          & 18               \\
      building     & 185        & Frank Zappa         & 16               \\
      center       & 180        & Isaac Asimov        & 20               \\
      form         & 172        & John Denver         & 16               \\
      game         & 267        & Karl Marx           & 13               \\
      lake         & 227        & Mary Astor          & 14               \\
      land         & 153        & Su Song             & 13               \\
      mythology    & 178        & Tupac Shakur        & 14               \\
      room         & 189        & \ldots              & \ldots           \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Ten words and a sample of 60 names used for constructing Holdout sets for WordNet and FreeBase, 
      respectively. The numbers of triples that each entity occurs in are listed to the right. 
      These triples comprise the Holdout sets.}
  \end{minipage}\hfill
  \mbox{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I've used

- [`fontenc`](//ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) to produce a better `\_` within the `t`ypewri`t`er font (used in the left-hand table);
- [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to provide better-looking tables.
- `\itshape` to distinguish a sub-heading within the right-hand table from other content within the same table.